# Kali Linux OllyDBG update to latest version

Tags: kali-linux

Kali Linux comes with Olly Debugger version 1.0.

How can i add the latest version to the Kali VM.  I have already tried apt-get update but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

OllyDbg is a program running on Wine. You'll have to download the binary from the authors website.